# Numeric Keypad and the text input is not visible in iOS screenshot

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uitextfield

I have set the `passwordTF.secureTextEntry = true` and everything is working fine the UITextField is getting masked . But I see that if take a **screenshot with the** **numeric keypad and masked input then the screenshot doesn't contains any keypad** **or text**. Everything is blank . **Is it the security feature of iOS for `secureTextEntry` ?**

I tried to search but could not find any specific documents and I am using iOS 14.6

Comment: yes, it's a feature. You can check other applications too.

Comment: ohhh any idea from which os it was introduced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for being late actually I found out that it is a security feature which is in action since iOS 13 itself so if you have a keyboard which is numeric and in case you have a text field with secure text masking on then the screenshot captured will not show the keyboard or the textfield contents

[Apple Discussion 1](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251035208)

[Apple Discussion 2](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251035283)